# Touch Event stay in view swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, touchesbegan

My situation is that i have two views, one view -> `MoveView` should be movable inside of the other view -> `FrameView`. But when moving the inner view, it can be moved outside the `FrameView`!? I hope all the `Views` didn't disturbed you ;D!

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var MoveViewLocation = CGPoint()
    super.touchesBegan(touches , withEvent:event)
    if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
        MoveViewLocation = touch.locationInView(FrameView)
        MoveView.center = MoveViewLocation
    }
}
```

Comment: Just restrict to the bounds?

Comment: Thanks Arbitur - Could you show me how to do this?

Comment: Just use if statements if view.x > frame.x { view.x = frame.x } and so on